# Node-Scheduler JavaScript looping its job

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to set shedulers to give users points for an event, but once I create the sheduler, it executes the job every minute after the date I set. Here s my code:

var date = "2020-07-1T23:58:00.410Z"
SheduleManager.addAvailabilitySheduler("5ebfba4562532456e30aae97", date, 20);

exports.addAvailabilitySheduler = (userId, date, nrOfPoints) => {
var convertedDate = new Date(date);

```
var givePointsSheduler = schedule.scheduleJob(convertedDate, function() {
    User.findOneAndUpdate( { _id: userId }, {
        '$inc': {
            balance: nrOfPoints
        }
    }).exec()
    .then(result => {
        console.log("Added points succesfully");
        console.log(new Date().toISOString());
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("error adding points");
    })

});
```

};

And the output for the console.log get printed  and executes the job every minute then

2020-07-13T20:58:00.179Z
Added points succesfully
2020-07-13T20:59:00.165Z
Added points succesfully
2020-07-13T21:00:00.152Z
Added points succesfully
2020-07-13T21:01:00.151Z